# 403 forbidden error after installing mod_security

Tags: php, apache, security, mod-security

I have installed mod_security & created some rules for exception for my domain. However I am still facing `403 forbidden` error for some of my scripts.

I have a php file named `myajax.php` which contains all codes which we call through java script ajax.I was not able to access some of the codes, however tracing the id from logs of mod_security.

I have modified the rules in `mod_security.conf` and used `SecRuleRemoveById` for those ID's. In some cases, I am not able to access php codes and there is no ID found in mod_security logs for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

403 Forbidden error is generally an issue with the http. Try installing the latest mod-security for your server. I was facing a similar issue for which I had to increase SecPcreMatchLimit 150000 SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion 150000 paramaters in modsecurity conf file. As I was using older version this did not work. For this you need to atleast have the 2.6 version. Hope this resolves your issue.